# Extending a control (ComboBox) in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, combobox, dependency-properties

I have a simple problem. I am trying to add a dependency property to a combo box. I want to be able to display a value on the face of the combo box when it is initially displayed.  There is a ContentPresenter with a TextBlock inside the ComboBox.   That TextBlock gets set when a user selects an item in the ComboBox. How can I set that with a default value (not one of the items)?  Show something like 'choose one'.

I can extend the ComboBox with a 'DefaultDisplay' dependency property but how do I 'link' that property to the TextBlock that is part of the control template?

Thanks for any help on this.

Pat

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a dependency property I'd suggest using a behavior to do this. I actually already had one of these written for this problem. Give it a try by adding it to your combobox and setting the PromptText property on the behavior:

```
public class ComboBoxPromptBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
{
    [Category("Display")]
    public string PromptText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PromptTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PromptTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PromptTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PromptText", typeof(string), typeof(ComboBoxPromptBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(" "));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Loaded);
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetPromptText();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Loaded);
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated -= new EventHandler(AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetPromptText();
    }

    private void SetPromptText()
    {
        var textbox = AssociatedObject.FindChild<TextBlock>();
        if (textbox != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text))
        {
            textbox.Text = PromptText;
        }
    }
}
```

And the extension method for FindChild is:

```
public static T FindChild<T>(this DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
        if (child is T)
        {
            return (T)child;
        }
        var match = child.FindChild<T>();
        if (match != null) return match;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: My system is not finding Behavior.  Research shows that it might be in Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity but it seems to be failing.

Comment: Yes, it is in the Expression Blend SDK http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3062